# Google Chrome issue while accessing variable of one javascript <script> tag in other <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I want to use a JavaScript variable named author from one `<script>` tag into other `<script>` tag on same page. I know it is a duplicate question but please my issue is a bit different.

I have declared that variable globally and used it in other `<script>` tag. It is working fine in IE, Edge, Firefox but in Chrome it doesn't. It looks like chrome don't even know if that variable exists. Here is the simple code:

```
<script>var author = "zubair";</script>
<script src="external.js"></script>
```

Comment: What error do you get in chrome console??? Is that a local file not served by any server?

Comment: I am not getting any error

Comment: So firstly clear chrome browser cache and retry and anyway you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue. We have no idea how you are trying to access this variable inside `external.js`. BTW, you said: `It looks like chrome don't even know if that variable exists` How that???

Comment: Thanks man clearing chache worked for me.